# Google mocking reading from device

Tags: googlemock

I have a mock to simulate reading data from a device. The problem I dont know how to set the buf value to simulate a reading. I wanna mock the buf value in the sensor.read(buf,sizeof(int)) function. Is there any way to do that? Se my code below:

Mock class:

```
class Device
{
 public:
  virtual int Read(char *buf, size_t size) = 0;
};

class MockDevice: public Device{
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD2(Read, int(char *buf, size_t size));
};
```

My class:

```
class Sensor
{
 private:
   Device *dev;

 public:
  Sensor(Device *device): dev(device);
  int DoRead(char *buf, size_t size){
    dev->Read(buf,size);
    // How can i set the buf here?
  }

}
```

The test:

```
TEST(DeviceReadTest, Read)
{
    char buf[10] = {0xAA}
    MockDevice *mockDevice = new MockDevice();

    EXPECT_CALL(*mockDevice, Read(_,_)).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(10));

    Sensor sensor(mockDevice);

    sensor.DoRead(buf,sizeof(buf)); // I wanna pass the buf content to the mock function. Is it possible?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
const char read_result[] = "abc";
EXPECT_CALL(*mockDevice, Read(_,_))
    .Times(1)
    .WillOnce(DoAll(
        SetArrayArgument<0>(
            read_result,
            read_result + strlen(read_result)),
        Return(strlen(read_result)));
```

You can find the full list of possible actions at https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Actions